# Solr Cloud - Facets

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to get facets returned in SoLR Cloud. I don't see the FACETS in the response.

localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=area&defType=lucene&debug=true

I didn't see any discussions around this. As faceting is a key feature, I believe it will be supported in Cloud too.

Is there anything I can check? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable faceting.
Try adding &facet=true

Comment: I did have that earlier, forgot to include it in the question. Will edit the question. 
So, what I get back is the facets response, with all counts 0. If I do distrib=false, I can see the facet counts from a shard. But in Cloud mode, I don't see the facet counts.

Comment: Ignore the question. It was a different issue with some old data set. Thanks Omoloro for the response. Marking it closed.